# Difference between Mobile - MobileConnect - Vote/Survey vs Email - Interaction - Triggered SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration

We are trying to send survey via SMS to subscribers.

So, we define survey and keywords on `Mobile - MobileConnect - Vote/Survey`. After finishing the configuration, we have clicked `Send`, but nothing happens.

We we did same configuration on `Email - Interaction - Triggered SMS` (we set different keywords!). Here, when we click `Send`, it sends first step of survey. But, when we have responded to survey(by sending keywords), we received `The keyword you specified was not recognized`.

When we respond with keyword of `Mobile - MobileConnect - Vote/Survey`, it was received by system successfully.

Long number is the same for both of them (MobileConnect and Triggered SMS). We did not find out how to define short number...

Can you explain what is the difference between Vote/Survey vs Triggered SMS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExactTarget currently supports two mobile messaging products - MobileConnect, and the legacy SMS Interactions product.

#### MobileConnect - [Documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/mobileconnect/)

> MobileConnect allows you to create, send, receive, and track mobile
> (SMS) messages. You can use MobileConnect to manage your available
> keywords, conduct sends to subscriber, automatically respond to
> incoming messages, and many other tasks outlined in this
> documentation. You can send and receive SMS messages using a short
> code within the United States and using short or long codes in other
> countries around the world. Each country requires its own short code,
> but you can use long codes to reach several different countries
> (depending on the general region).

#### SMS Interactions - [Documentation](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/mobile_messages/)

> SMS messages connect you directly to your subscriber via a mobile
> device in a timely fashion, so you can conceivably interact with your
> subscriber wherever they may be at any time. You can take advantage of
> this connection to provide information, offers, or opt-in messages
> wherever your subscribers may be at the time. SMS messages are less
> intrusive than voice messages and are shorter and more immediate than
> email messages.

These two systems operate very differently, and independent of one another. MobileConnect utilizes Contacts, while SMS uses data extensions.

Short/Long codes are based on the level of product purchased, and how your account has been set up.  You would need to contact your account representative to add any codes to your account.